# Differential equations first order

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential

How to find the particular the solution for this differential equation 
$x y'(x)-y(x)(1+x^2)=\frac{x^2}{2}$ 
first i solved it as homogenous differential equation as follows 
$xy'(x)-y(x)(1+x^2)=0$ then i got $y(x)=ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}}x$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ y'(x)+P(x)y(x)=Q(x)$$
then
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\mu(x)}\left(\int \mu(x)Q(x)dx+c\right)$$
where
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int P(x)dx\right)$$
we have
$$ y'(x)-\frac{(1+x^2)}{x}y(x)=\frac{x}{2}$$
$$\mu(x)=\exp\left(-\int \frac{1+x^2}{x}dx\right)=\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$ 
$$y(x)=xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\left(\int \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+c\right)$$

Comment: thank you very much  i got the idea ,